# Retrieving mySQL password/username for phpmyadmin, using MAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, mamp

I've set up a mySQL database, and I want to be access that database using phpmyadmin. However, when I try to access this database, I am prompted to type a username and password. First of all, WHAT username and password is this? Is it one I created with mySQL? If so, how do I locate that username and password. I am using MAMP.

Answer (score 11):

Username and password: root

See this link to change password: http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/faq.html#q9

Comment: To clarify, it's prompting you for the (MySQL) database username and password.

Comment: @Ami, sorry don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Just answering the OP's question. "First of all, WHAT username and password is this?"